# Which is right: "what pants is he wearing" or "what pants are he wearing"?

Tags: grammatical-number, word-order, verb-agreement, errors

Since 'pants' is one of those always plural words, I can't figure out which sounds right.

Comment: Not as a duplicate but as a NARQ. See my comment @tchrist below.

Answer (score 2):

<sub>My dup-close vote was miscast, so let me make amends by supplying an answer.  That said, I feel like this is actually **General Reference**, and far too simple for this site. It’s part of the fundamental mechanics of how numeric concordance between subject and verb works, and it is hardly limited to English alone.  This is a very, very common feature of many languages.</sub>

---

The bottom line is that ***word order does not matter***.  The grammatical number of the subject dictates the grammatical number of that subject’s verb. The subject of the sentence is not *pants* but *he*.

Because you would always say

> He is wearing those pants.

and not

> He *are wearing those pants.

in just the same fashion, you must therefore ask

> He is wearing what pants?
>   What pants is he wearing?

and never

> He *are wearing what pants?
>   What pants *are he wearing?

because the subject is *he* and thus the corresponding verb must be singular.

This is just like how when you rearrange this sentence:

> The boy races down the streets.

into this:

> Down the streets races the boy.

That the new proximity of *streets* to the verb has no effect whatsoever upon the number of that verb, because *streets* is still not the subject. *Boy* is.

Similarly, in

> The woman carrying three purses looks ready to drop one.

Just because *purses* is near the verb does not change the number of that verb, since its subject is actually the singular *woman* rather than the plural *purses*.

Comment: +1 I would add though that *"what pants is he wearing*" sounds odd and because of that a native speaker (who cared) might switch to something like, "Which pants does he have on?" or "Which pants has he got on?"

Comment: Your dup-close vote was indeed miscast. It should have been NARQ-close instead. The question is a trick and this answer falls right into it! "What cars is he going to buy?" not "What cars are he going to buy?" Don't fall for Qs as this.